# priority queue as min heap c++ vs heapq in python (how to convert heapq.heappop(openList) to c++?)

Tags: python, c++, oop, c++14

I have the following python code:

```
    import heapq
    heapq.heappush(openList, currentSearchNode)
    #NOTE List of nodes that have been checked
    closedList = []
    while openList:
        #NOTE Pop the lowest fscore (to-go + been from or gScore + hScore) and set it as current
        currentSearchNode = heapq.heappop(openList)
...
```

I need to convert it to C++14, I tried this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
priority_queue <Node, vector<Node>, greater<Node>> min_heap;
vector<Node> openList, closeList;
Node currentNode = Node(start, euclidean(start, end), 0);
min_heap.emplace(openList, currentNode);
while (!openList.empty()) {
    currentNode = min_heap.pop(openList);
...
}
```

The only problem in Visual Studio that pops up in red, is this line `currentNode = min_heap.pop(openList);` as you can see, it says, too many argument for pop. How to do it the right way?

Comment: `priority_queue's pop` doesn't take any arguments [`cppreference - pop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop)

Comment: @pvc I read that, but what is my alternative to convert the python code?

Comment: how about using [`top`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top) method to get first element, then using `pop` to remove

Comment: @pvc please what is this in C++ heapq.heapify(openList)?

Comment: I am not sure, that we have direction stl function to turn a list into heap queue, you might have to write your own function to do the job for you. and if it's complete different question, what you asked above, it's best to start new question, rather than continuing hear

Comment: I think it exists, I mean if there is no heapify for priority queue, then priority queue must do the job some other way?

Comment: STL has function in algorithm library [`make_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) from range, if that's what you looking for

Comment: @pvc right, that can help, though I ve made my own heap implementation. Can you take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63654034/class-definition-in-python-with-missing-and-setitem-hard-to-convert-to-c ?

Comment: @user13584915 This is exactly why you don't use another language (python) as a model in writing C++ code.  There is a [std::make_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) function that does all this work for you already.

Comment: What do you mean? Please give details what are you referring to?

Comment: You are going down the wrong path of taking code written in one language, and attempting to do a line-by-line translation of that code to C++.  That will lead to programs that are buggy, inefficient, or just plain weird looking to a C++ programmer.  The heap facilities in C++ are given by `std::make_heap` along with `push_heap`, `pop_heap` etc.  When a C++ sees usages of those functions, that programmer immediately knows what is being done, and not try to figure out some home-made python-like code written as C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you mean I don't need to use priority_queue <Node, vector<Node>, greater<Node>> min_heap; at all? I can only rely on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/ ?

Comment: You can use `priority_queue`, but you only used that because that is what the python code was doing.  Don't use what you did in another language as a guide in writing C++ code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so, in other words for my problem, I can make use of `make_heap` instead of `priority_queue` for python `heapq`, is that what you re saying?

Comment: Also, I can't use `priority_queue` for my problem as I need to heapify for every iteration. Right?

Comment: You can use `priority_queue` or the heap functions.  My main point is not to take another language's way of doing things and try to do a line-by-line translation from that language to C++.

Comment: I get it, but how can I do heapify if I opt for the `priority_queue` implementation?

Comment: can you help with this one please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63654034/class-definition-in-python-with-missing-and-setitem-hard-to-convert-to-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like below;

```
while (!min_heap.empty()) {
     currentNode = min_heap.top(); // sets the top small (since std::greater used)element to currentNode;
     
     /* do something with currentNode */

     min_heap.pop(); // pops the element from container  
}
```